# scrollsToTop not working in UIPageViewController when swiped

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

When setting the view controller by pressing on a button to change to the next "page", scrollsToTop works fine inside each View Controller, using:

```
myPageViewController.setViewControllers(...
```

However after **SWIPING** to go to the next page instead of button press, scrollsToTop does not work.

Any solution? Or shall I just file a bug report?

Comment: your need to post more code. probably just a bug on your side.

Comment: It works when using a button to go the view controller but not when I use Apple's built in swipe feature to go to the same view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling to top is disabled (or the behavior is undefined) if multiple `UIScrollView` instances have `scrollsToTop` enabled. Is it possible that's the case?

Comment: It shouldn't be unless there's a bug in Apple's viewControllersArray. Like I say, the only issue happens after swiping, not in the view controller's logic.

Comment: You can check whether that's the case by inspecting the page view controller's scroll view in Xcode's UI inspector.